# Was Kris Kringle really Santa?

Tags: character, miracle-on-34th-street

In *Miracle On 34th Street*, Kris Kringle claims to be Santa, which is "proven" in the courts, although the prosecution seemed to claim insanity.

Was it ever confirmed in the movie as to whether he was delusional, a liar, Santa, or just a really, really good "Mall Santa"? Have I misunderstood a key element of the plot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key element of the plot you missed was ***doubt about Kringle***. The entire point was that no one really knows, including the audience. No answer was ever given to this effect. You either believe in Santa or you don't...